# HTML TAG <A> pass variable both with href and onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, href

I want when someone clicks this link to go first on myfunction that I have in JS and after that follow the href function that exists in `<a>` tag. The problem is that it follows first the href and I can't pass the variable I want from the js function.

here is my code:

**PHP**

```php
echo '<a href="category.php?id=' . $_SESSION['id'] . '" onclick="myFunction();">
        <div class="icon-lock">
            <img  src="/test/images/lock.png" alt="Locked Button" width="35" height="35" border="0">
        </div>';
echo '</a>';
```

**JS**

```javascript
<script>
function myFunction() {
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {id: "1"},
        url: "category.php"
        });
 }
</script>
```

I am very confused on how href and myfunction will work in order to print

```php
$id=$_POST['id'];
echo $id;
```

in php after the page has been reloaded...
Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the purpose of reloading page ?

Comment: i want the page to be reloaded and then based on if the user clicked on the link print a different icon that before..as you see i have a lock.png image in my code but if the link is pressed then i have an if that if (!(id==null)) then print lock.png else print unlock.png..and for the purpose of this i first have to pass the id from the session as category.php?id= session['id'] but also to pass the var id from javascript that i want to check on the same page to print another image. i hope you understand what i want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the 'id' as a parameter in your function and use javascript to change the window location after the ajax is successful.

**HTML**

```
<div class="icon-lock">
    <img onclick="myFunction(<?=$_SESSION['id']?>)" src="/test/images/lock.png" alt="Locked Button" width="35" height="35" border="0">
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function myFunction(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {id: "1"},
        url: "category.php",
        success: function() {
            window.location.assign("category.php?id="+id);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer but it doesnt work when i press in the image..the id that i want to be returned is not.Look at my code as i have it now:

Comment: PHP:

`echo '<a href="category.php">
          <div class="icon-lock">
<img  onclick="myFunction('.$_SESSION['id'].')" src="/test/images/lock.png" alt="Locked Button" width="35" height="35" border="0">
           </div>';
             echo '</a>';`

javascript:

`unction myFunction(id) {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {id: "1"},
            url: "category.php"
            });
            success: function() {
            window.location.assign("category.php?id="+id);
        }
 }`

Comment: What am i doing wrong? i want to pass both variable $_SESSION['id'] and the id that i have as data posted in the javascript..so actually i want 2 variables passed when the page is refreshed and i want to print that 'id' variable i have in javascript later in the php code by using `$id=$_POST['id'];
echo $id;`

Answer (score 1):

you do simply pass this on your function

your php code will look like this

```
 echo '<a href="category.php?id=' . $_SESSION['id'] . '" onclick="myFunction(this);">/*pass this keyword to function */
            <div class="icon-lock">
                <img  src="/test/images/lock.png" alt="Locked Button" width="35" height="35" border="0">
            </div>';
    echo '</a>';

function myFunction(str) {
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: str.getAttribute("href")
   }).done(function() {
        // What ever following the link does
            window.location.href=str.getAttribute("href")

   });
}
```

Comment: i replaced my js with

`function myFunction(str) {
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: str.getAttribute("href")
   }).done(function() {
        window.location.replace("index.php?id="+str);
   });
}`

Comment: and my php with 

`echo '<a href="category.php?id=' . $_SESSION['id'] . '" onclick="myFunction(this);">
           <div class="icon-lock">
            <img  src="/test/images/lock.png" alt="Locked Button" width="35" height="35" border="0">
           </div>';
             echo '</a>';
              $id=$_POST['id'];
             echo $id;`

Comment: but it always redirects to category.php without passind the var id to index.php(index was just to check where it goes..actually i want it to be refreshed and send category.php?id=$_SESSION['id'] + id='1')

Comment: @Johnny i made an edit to my code hope this will help you

Comment: yes i want to refresh the page after ajax call so i can pass another variable in my page if the link is clicked.
I replaced my js with
`function myFunction(str) {
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: str.getAttribute("href")
   }).done(function() {
        window.location.href=str.getAttribute("href")

   });
}`

but it just reloads the page as href on <a> tag suggests with just passing $_SESSION['id]' and not the id variable that i want to set to 1 if the link is pressed.

Comment: @Johnny if you just want to reload i suggest  use
 location.reload()

Comment: reloading is of course my purpose here but passing $_session['id'] is essential for my page to load and when the specific link is pressed i also want to pass another variable..lets say $check=1 so in my php page i want to check if $check == NULL or not..of course the first time the page loads the $check will be null but if a user clicks on the link the $check will have the value 1 so it will execute the code i 've written in there.I dont know if u cant understand me since i am not good at all at explaining..sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the default action in your `myfunction` method which takes the event object.  And then in the success call back of your ajax request, do what ever you wanna do .

`<a href="category.php?id=' . $_SESSION['id'] . '" onclick="myFunction(e);">`

```
function myFunction(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {id: "1"},
        url: "category.php"
   }).done(function() {
        // What ever following the link does
   });
}
```

Comment: i tried also your way but it just doesnt follow the javascript...it just refresh immediately without sending it to the file i wrote..to check which one is gotten first i wrote 

`
$id='1';
<a href="category.php?id=' . $_SESSION['id'] . '" onclick="myFunction('.$id.');">`

and in js i wrote to go in another php page but it always goes to category.php
`
function myFunction(id) {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {id: "1"},
            url: "category.php"
            })
            .done(function() {
       window.location.assign("index.php?id="+id);
   });
 }`

Comment: @Johnny.. Can you check the edit. i forgot to prevent the default action.